# Flutter "globaloverlay.support()" doesn't work when its on material app

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification

Well the problem I am having here, normally if I wrap materialApp with global overlay support, it should be working, but it is not as you can see from debug console. Any suggestions? I am normally trying integrate firebase on iOS. The restart app is causing problem I guess, but I do not want to throw it out, to saying truth

```
        // ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, duplicate_ignore
    
    import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:medicte/pages/home_page.dart';
    import 'package:animated_splash_screen/animated_splash_screen.dart';
    import 'package:overlay_support/overlay_support.dart';
    import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
    import 'firebase_options.dart';
    
    Future _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
      }
    }
    
    main() {
      runApp(RestartWidget(child: MyApp()));
    }
    
    Future<void> initializeDefault() async {
      FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Initialized default app $app');
      }
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(428, 926),
      builder: (context, child) => OverlaySupport.global(
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: SplashScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
    }
    
    class RestartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      const RestartWidget({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);
    
      final Widget child;
    
      static void restartApp(BuildContext context) {
        context.findAncestorStateOfType<_RestartWidgetState>()?.restartApp();
      }
    
      @override
      // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
      _RestartWidgetState createState() => _RestartWidgetState();
    }
    
    class _RestartWidgetState extends State<RestartWidget> {
      late final FirebaseMessaging _messaging;
      PushNotification? _notificationInfo;
      void requestAndRegisterNotification() async {
        // 1. Initialize the Firebase app
        await initializeDefault();
    
        // 2. Instantiate Firebase Messaging
        _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
        FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    
        // 3. On iOS, this helps to take the user permissions
        NotificationSettings settings = await _messaging.requestPermission(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          provisional: false,
          sound: true,
        );
    
        if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('User granted permission');
          }
          String? token = await _messaging.getToken();
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("The token is ${token!}");
          }
          // For handling the received notifications
          FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
            // Parse the message received
            PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
              title: message.notification?.title,
              body: message.notification?.body,
            );
            if (kDebugMode) {
              print("The notification is $notification");
            }
    
            setState(() {
              _notificationInfo = notification;
            });
            if (_notificationInfo != null) {
              // For displaying the notification as an overlay
              showSimpleNotification(
                Text(_notificationInfo!.title!),
                subtitle: Text(_notificationInfo!.body!),
                background: Colors.cyan.shade700,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              );
            }
          });
        } else {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
          }
        }
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        requestAndRegisterNotification();
        FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
          PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
            title: message.notification?.title,
            body: message.notification?.body,
          );
          setState(() {
            _notificationInfo = notification;
          });
        });
    
        super.initState();
      }
    
      Key key = UniqueKey();
    
      void restartApp() {
        setState(() {
          key = UniqueKey();
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return KeyedSubtree(
          key: key,
          child: widget.child,
        );
      }
    }
    
    class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AnimatedSplashScreen(
          splash: Image.asset(
              'lib/images/MedicteLogo-4a2e31cd2358bb08ff8d12acb2761357.png'),
          nextScreen: HomePage(),
          splashTransition: SplashTransition.scaleTransition,
          pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade,
        );
      }
    }
    
    class PushNotification {
      PushNotification({
        this.title,
        this.body,
      });
      String? title;
      String? body;
    }
```

1. Heading

This is my debug console:

```
>2022-09-02 12:02:26.023971+0300 Runner[19573:866637] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-09-02 12:02:26.194783+0300 Runner[19573:866637] Could not load the "LaunchImage" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.example.medicte"
2022-09-02 12:02:26.208267+0300 Runner[19573:866829] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
2022-09-02 12:02:26.236111+0300 Runner[19573:866823] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `FirebaseApp.configure()` to your application initialization. This can be done in in the App Delegate's application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI). Read more: https:/goo.gl/ctyzm8.
2022-09-02 12:02:26.237231+0300 Runner[19573:866823] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `FirebaseApp.configure()` to your application initialization. This can be done in in the App Delegate's application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (or the `@main` struct's initializer in SwiftUI). Read more: https:/goo.gl/ctyzm8.
2022-09-02 12:02:26.279437+0300 Runner[19573:866849] flutter: The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:51958/HXJzT6ZmSJY=/
2022-09-02 12:02:26.614633+0300 Runner[19573:866825] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
2022-09-02 12:02:26.836889+0300 Runner[19573:866830] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
2022-09-02 12:02:26.912218+0300 Runner[19573:866823] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2022-09-02 12:02:26.922498+0300 Runner[19573:866833] flutter: Initialized default app FirebaseApp([DEFAULT])
2022-09-02 12:02:26.922884+0300 Runner[19573:866823] 9.4.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '204532241696'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
2022-09-02 12:02:27.019553+0300 Runner[19573:866833] flutter: User granted permission
2022-09-02 12:02:29.000587+0300 Runner[19573:866833] flutter: The token is c1P2bEEh9Et3njcfkiOntp:APA91bFZIAR4oxrrwi0aJuYVofPC93x6wjy39TCTUt8-w6PkxtDgKTQUv-iQamhnd_pox6q2mm4JvBD6hSBS3bWmbzp8BO0LhpR89PvMwJv5ZdPWokguVkpMW6t5YUdIfVPwhlfTpsY5
2022-09-02 12:02:38.677058+0300 Runner[19573:866833] flutter: The notification is Instance of 'PushNotification'
2022-09-02 12:02:38.681029+0300 Runner[19573:866833] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:overlay_support/src/overlay_state_finder.dart': Failed assertion: line 12 pos 7: '_debugInitialized': Global OverlaySupport Not Initialized ! 
ensure your app wrapped widget OverlaySupport.global
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
#2      findOverlayState (package:overlay_support/src/overlay_state_finder.dart:12:7)
#3      showOverlay (package:overlay_support/src/overlay.dart:63:26)
#4      showOverlayNotification (package:overlay_support/src/notification/overlay_notification.dart:21:10)
#5      showSimpleNotification (package:overlay_support/src/notification/overlay_notification.dart:97:17)
#6      _RestartWidgetState.requestAndRegisterNotification.<anonymous closure> (package:medicte/main.dart:106:11)
#7      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#9      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#10     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#11     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
#12     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
#13     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1418:47)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
#16     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
#17     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
#18     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1426:13)
#19     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
#20     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
#21     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
#22     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#23     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, error is `Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.`

If you didn't initialize the Firebase project, start with  and follow this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios)

```
firebase init
```

After all done, you will find

[image]